# iphone simulator do not respond

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

my iphone simulator sometimes don't respond to any user interface exept the home button. 
I lauched an app,it works all right,howerver after 2 or 3 clicks on the UI,it freeze,and do not respond any more, the only way makes it work again is click the home button.

Comment: Post some code or define your view hierarchy.

Comment: Maybe your app throws an exception and the debugger stops at a breakpoint and you didn't notice.

Comment: Yes, @phix23 has a good suggestion. You can pull up the console by typing Command-Shift-Y in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody comes to this thread searching for solution on cross platform , Xamarin with setup

Mac OS Version: 10.15.4 (19E266)
Visual Studio Version: VS 2019 Professional 8.5.1
Xamarin.iOS Version: 13.16.0.11
XCode Version: 11.4

,,this was bug which is fixed in quick update 8.5.2 by Xamarin team